# Python subprocess returned non-zero exit status -6

Tags: python, django

this is my first post on stackoverflow. I hope my question is not to stupid:)

I'm using django to develop a website, inside the django I need to grab thumbnail of website, so I use https://github.com/coderholic/PyWebShot to achieve it.

I run PyWebShot in django shell with subprocess it work well, but when I put django into apache2 and access it with a url then it fail.

Here is the error message:

> CalledProcessError at GIVEN_URL
>
> Command '['echo', '$HOME']' returned non-zero exit status -6

It fail on this command actually:

```
subprocess.check_output(['echo', '$HOME'])
```

I've tried write output and error of the process into a file, but the file always empty.

I'm hoping someone can give me a note or direction, Thanks!

ps: If need more information please just let me know.

Comment: Probably a permission issue since the deployed app would be running as a user other than you and will write to a different area than where you wrote to. Check your Apache error logs and then try to replicate the scenario.

Comment: Output is contained in the exceptions `output` attribute if that helps any. Just catch the exception, `except CalledProcessError as e`, and use the attribute, `e.output`.

Comment: I check Apache error logs and find a strange error. After that I surf the internet and found it is a old python2.7 error. So I patch it then solved this problem! Thanks everybody.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I check Apache error logs and find a strange error. After that I surf the internet and found it is a old python2.7 error. So I patch it then solved this problem! Thanks everybody.

Answer (score 1):

The "echo" command may not be available to the apacher server (depends on the value of PATH, not necessarily same as when you run it manually). More likely though, the $HOME env var is not defined for the account running the Apache server. There is a standard set of env vars available to CGI scripts (see for instance http://www.perlfect.com/articles/cgi_env.shtml or even the [CGI spec itself](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-robinson-www-interface-00)). Finally, apache's mod_env module allows you to pass some env vars to scripts, you would specify those in your httpd.conf.

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely a [bug](https://answers.launchpad.net/mg5amcnlo/+question/270603) reported in Python 2.7.2. Upgrading to a newer version should resolve the issue.

The error reported in the apache logs is something along the lines of:

```
Fatal Python error: Couldn't create autoTLSkey mapping
```